# looking for awk formatting syntax

Tags: awk

How do I format output in awk ? or ksh print commands

I have a file

```
bash-3.2# cat filename
host    1
host1   2       1
host2   3       2       1
host3   1       2
host4   3       2       1
```

Looking to align output like below.

```
host1           2       1
host2   3       2       1
host3           2       1
host4   3       2       1
host5                   1
```

Comment: I don't really see the pattern...

Comment: The pattern is to print nothing when there's no value, and to put the values in descending numeric order.

Comment: @doubleDown Align all numbers in their own column in decreasing order?

Comment: Why does "host" transform into "host5"?

Comment: where did the `2` in `host1` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a typo in your sample data (host 1 is actually host5 1). You can do something like this with **`GNU awk`**:

#### Content of script.awk:

```
NR==FNR {
    for (c = 2 ; c <= NF ; c++) {
        high = (high > $c) ? high : $c
    }
    next
}
{
    delete a
    delete b
    n = p = shift = 0
    printf "%s\t",$1
    for (i = 2 ; i <= NF ; i++) {
        a[$i]
    }
    n = asorti(a,b)
    for (x = n ; x > 0 ; x--) {
        if (b[x] < high) { shift = high - b[x] }
            while (++p <= shift) {
            printf "\t"
        }
        printf "%s\t", b[x]
        }
    print ""
}
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
host1   2   1
host2   3   2   1
host3   1   2
host4   3   2   1
host5   1

$ gawk -f script.awk file file
host1       2   1   
host2   3   2   1   
host3       2   1   
host4   3   2   1   
host5           1   

$ cat file2
host1   2   1
host2   3   2   1
host3   1   2
host4   3   5   1
host5   1

$ gawk -f script.awk file2 file2
host1               2   1   
host2           3   2   1   
host3               2   1   
host4   5       3       1   
host5                   1
```